# Copy data from 2 columns in to 1 column in another table MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to copy winners of a match stored in `tblFixtures` in to a single column in `tblEntrants`. So I basically want a winners list created in column `AccountID` in `tblEntrants` like this...

```
tblFixtures Columns: Player1 resultPLayer1 Player2 ResultPlayer2, CompID
                       john        5         stu         2        (Guid) 
                       dave        0         max         5        (Guid)

tblEntrants Columns: AccountID, CompID
                        john    (Guid)
                        dave    (Guid)
```

Here's what I have tried so far but it doesn't work..

```
INSERT INTO tblEntrants(AccountID,compID) SELECT(CASE WHEN (SELECT resultplayer1 FROM tblfixtures) > (SELECT resultplayer2 FROM tblfixtures) THEN (SELECT player1 FROM tblfixtures) END), @compID

INSERT INTO tblEntrants(AccountID,compID) SELECT(CASE WHEN (SELECT resultplayer2 FROM tblfixtures) > (SELECT resultplayer2 FROM tblfixtures) THEN (SELECT player2 FROM tblfixtures) END), @compID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
INSERT INTO tblEntrants(AccountID,compID) 
SELECT CASE WHEN ResultPlayer2 > resultPLayer1 THEN Player2 ELSE Player1 END, CompID
FROM tblfixtures
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was simple but I'm still just learning here. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS:** you can do it using single `SELECT` statement with `CASE`

```
INSERT INTO tblEntrants(AccountID,compID)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN resultPLayer1 > ResultPlayer2 THEN player1 ELSE player2 END, @compID
FROM tblFixtures
```